# From live site to a localhost Javascript Errors

Tags: javascript, fancybox, joomla2.5

I'm quite new to Javascript, I copied my live site to localhost so I could work on it without having to touch the live site. The local site looks just like the live site, but doesn't work like it at all.

The Fancybox box popups aren't working now, and these are the errors I'm getting on my console log:

```
index.php?option=com_users&view=custom&layout=default_step4:107 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionindex.php?option=com_users&view=custom&layout=default_step4:107 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 p.Callbacks.kjquery.min.js:2 p.Callbacks.l.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 p.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 D
index.php?option=com_users&view=custom&layout=default_step4:399 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionindex.php?option=com_users&view=custom&layout=default_step4:399 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 v.Callbacks.ljquery.min.js:2 v.Callbacks.c.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 v.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 A
all.js:61 Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.
all.js:61 FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
kallyas_script.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionkallyas_script.js:32 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 v.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:2 v.event.add.o.handle.u
index.php?option=com_users&view=custom&layout=default_step4:336 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionindex.php?option=com_users&view=custom&layout=default_step4:336 reportindex.php?option=com_users&view=custom&layout=default_step4:480 onchange
```

Comment: Look in Firebug or the developer console and look to see if any of the resources didn't load.

Comment: Does your localhost support php? you cannot make local php calls like `index.php?option=xxxx` if it doesn't. You may need to set the full path to the server where the php file is hosted like `http://example.com/index.php?option=xxxx`